# mysql insert rows in multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with multiple tables, in al the tables there have to be a row because else my query is going wrong. In one of my insert pages i insert al the rows seperatly in the tables. Is there a more efficient and safe way to do this? Maybe in Mysql (CASCADE)?

Answer (score 0):

afaik there is no other way to same data into different tables in same statement.
But you can try using transactions.

```
START TRANSACTION;
insert into t1 (field1, field2) values ('data1','data2');
```

After inserting the data you can check them if they are ok and if everything is like expected than commit your queries:

```
COMMIT;
```

or do a rollback, which removes the changes sience "START TRANSACTION".

```
ROLLBACK;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a MySQL Transaction, which allows you to rollback the inserts if one of them fails. SQL to start the transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;
```

At this point, do your inserts, if one of them errors then rollback:

```
ROLLBACK;
```

If all of the inserts complete with no errors, you can commit your inserts:

```
COMMIT;
```

[MySQL docs for transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)